# Contour to DEM interpolation

Tags: dem, contour

I am using the Topo to Raster tool to convert contours to a DEM, the DEM is ~90% accurate, however in some locations in the DEM the interpolation produces values higher or lower than what the contours tell us the elevation should be. Refer to red arrows in the attached image for some of these locations.[image]

Comment: Try repair geometry on your contours, it looks like you have some bowtie/self-intersections.

Comment: I thought I fixed those, can you please tell me where you see one in the attached image?

Comment: I can't see specifically, they're often too small to see even when zoomed in but from experience your results look like they are caused by geometry errors